# How to iterate through an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to iterate over an array using ruby and it is miserably failing,

```
My Array
people = [{first_name: "Gary", job_title: "car enthusiast", salary: "14000" },
{first_name: "Claire", job_title: "developer", salary: "15000"},
{first_name: "Clem", job_title: "developer", salary: "12000"}]
```

How to iterate over the above hash to output only the salary value???

I tried using:

```
people.each do |i,j,k|
  puts "#{i}"
end
```

The results are as below and is not what i was intending,

```
{:first_name=>"Gary", :job_title=>"car enthusiast", :salary=>"14000"}
{:first_name=>"Claire", :job_title=>"developer", :salary=>"15000"}
{:first_name=>"Clem", :job_title=>"developer", :salary=>"12000"}
```

Is there a way to iterate through this array and simply list out only the salary values and not the rest?

Comment: `people.each { |person| puts person[:salary] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In newer versions of Ruby (not sure when it was introduced, probably around ruby 2.0-ish which is when I believe keyword arguments were introduced), you can do:

```
people.each do |salary:,**|
  puts salary
end
```

where `**` takes all the keyword arguments that you don't name and swallows them (ie, the `first_name` and `job_title` keys in the hash). If that isn't something that your ruby version allows, you'll need to just store the entire hash in the variable:

```
people.each do |person|
  puts person[:salary]
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the values in the same line,

My query is now run as 

people.each {|x| puts x[:job_title], x[:first_name], x[:salary]}

Currently the output is as follows:

192:rubyfiles root# ruby test.rb
car enthusiast
Gary
14000
developer
Claire
15000
developer
Clem
12000

Comment: Okay so it shows each value on a separate line and you just want it all on one line? You could do `p [x[:job_title], x[:first_name], x[:salary]]` or just use any of ruby's string formatting options or its string interpolation

Comment: still the same results. 

car enthusiast
Gary
14000
developer
Claire
15000
developer
Clem
12000

people.each {|x| puts [x[:job_title], x[:first_name], x[:salary]]}

Comment: [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) not `puts`...there's a difference

Comment: I wonder how to use named keyword arguments in ruby > 2.7, when you iterate over an array of hashes